# How do I set my parameter in my Database constructor as it takes in a list of Messages?

Tags: java, constructor, extend

```
public class Database extends Message {

private List<Message> messages;

public Database(List<Message> messages) {
    // what do I do here?
}
```

// methods sorting the list of messages

```
public class Message {

private Optional<String> contactName;
private String to;
private String from;
private String body;
private LocalDateTime date;
private boolean isImportant;

public Message(Optional<String> contactName, String to, String from,
               String body, LocalDateTime date, boolean isImportant) {
    this.contactName = contactName;
    this.to = to;
    this.from = from;
    this.body = body;
    this.date = date;
    this.isImportant = isImportant;
```

//getters and setters here

---

I am confused as to how my constructor for my `Database` class is supposed to look. I have looked up so much and have gotten nothing or I'm maybe over thinking this. My database class takes in a `List<Message> parameter`. I have a class called Message that takes in different params. The Message class also has their respectable getters and setters. I'm only allowed to have that one constructor in my Database class that has the `List<Message>` parameter. My problem here is getting my `Database constructor` to properly have each of the indexes in the list to have their values in the Message constructor?

---

Edits:
My message class has a constructor which takes in params and has their respective getters and setters.

My database class has a a constructor with a list (of type message) param. This class also has sorting methods which I am creating, but I also must call methods from my message class such as getContactName().

When I tried to do:

```
public Database(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }
```

I received an 'actual and formal argument list differ in length' error.

Comment: It would help if you explained what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Would help if You add more description of what You are trying to do. 
Right now database class seems like container model for messages
so constructor should just initialize class with some messages. so in that case it should look like this:

```
public Database(List<Message> messages) {
this.messages = messages;
}
```

Also given Your description, extension of Database class with Message is not needed.

EDIT:

Considering Your comments . You want something like following.

```
public class Database extends Message {
    private List<Message> messages;

    public Database(Optional<String> contactName, String to, String from, String body, LocalDateTime date, boolean isImportant){
    super(contactName, to, from, body, date, isImportant);
    this.messages = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

that way. You can create Message with list of messages related to message in database.
used empty list of messages because I feel like it needs to be added later not at constructor.

I got confused when I first read Database class that contains list of messages

Comment: I have re-edited my description! When I did the above, I received an error and I was thinking of extending as I need to call methods from the Message class occasionally.

Comment: You cannot extend Database with Message in that case. 
Database contains list of objects with differs in content. if You want to use methods. do it per message object. therefore iterate over list and use those methods. 
please specify what "occassionally" use case would look like so it will be easier to provide with answer.  

the error occurs because You dont call constructor of extended class to fill values. remove it to solve the problem .

Comment: I feel like You dont exactly know what You are doing. 
Let me clear that up . 

You are creating Database object witch extends Message object . 
so You are getting Database object that contains list of messages. 
And additionaly all fields from message object.
by all fields I mean 

private Optional<String> contactName;
private String to;
private String from;
private String body;
private LocalDateTime date;
private boolean isImportant;

I can imagine that is not what You are trying to do

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do. I want a database object that contains a list of messages with all the fields from the message object.